# Bulk download PDF media in Sitecore Media Library

Tags: media-library

Is there any way if we can download bulk PDF (or any media) from Sitecore Media Library?

Basically we have to change one logo in all PDFs in Media Library and re-upload all.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to do both.

Right after you install you can bulk download from the media library using the context menu options.

You can selectively download in a package or just download everything.

- Download - Used to download a regular zip of the files.
- Packaging - Used to generate a Sitecore zip package of the items.

[image: Bulk Download]

You can also use SPE to bulk upload through the PowerShell Remoting module.

Comment: ok from marketplace I downloaded 
4.6 for Sitecore 8 Full 4.6 release for Sitecore 8 version of SPD Will that work out
I installed this modules and right clicked but couldn't fine that Script option in context menu

Comment: Any idea on above

Comment: Are you logged in as admin? Do you see the console and ISE? Issues running commands?

Comment: Yeah I tried on Sitecore Vanilla instance and logged in with Admin.
1. I couldn't see structure as per above screen-shot
2. When I click on Console , PowerShell console , Reporting tool --> PowerShell reports I'm ended up with Sitecore login screen
3. all these links Layout, Download , Packaging , Cleanup Data folder is not visible to me

Comment: Can you double check that the `\App_Config\Include\Cognifide.PowerShell.config` is enabled?

Comment: It's enable I can read it as Cognifide.PowerShell.config

Comment: I recommend you reach out to the #module-spe channel on Sitecore Slack Chat. It will be easier to help troubleshoot any installation issues with SPE.

Comment: Ok how can we connect on Sitecore Slack Chat. Meanwhile can you tell me is there any way to download all PDF I mean by creating package or something else

Comment: There is a link on the page here: https://www.akshaysura.com/2015/10/27/how-to-join-sitecore-slack-community-chat/