# Issue while downloading multiple files with Send-File command

Tags: powershell-extensions

Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 6.2.0.29687
Sitecore 10.1
Windows PowerShell 5.1

What I am trying to do:
I have filtered out a few files based on certain conditions.
So, I have filtered out the files and am using `Send-File -NoDialog` to download the files.

Problem: After downloading the first file, it does not download the remaining files.

Comment: Perhaps related to this issue https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/991

Comment: Not sure with send-file command but I used this approach to modify the zip logic and was able to download the multiple files. Here is my answer. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32685/bulk-download-media-library-in-sitecore-media-library-without-encoding-file-name